# how to find changed substring

Tags: java, gwt

I'm creating an application in GWT and scan the text in my RichTextArea every 0.5 seconds. The difference between the oldText and newText should be logged with one or more ChangeEvents.

```
new InsertEvent(int position, String substring)
new DeleteEvent(int position, int length)
```

How would be the best way to find one or several Changes between those strings? For example:

**one Event**

```
String oldText = "Hello world!";
String newText = "Hello woarld!";
ChangeEvent one = new InsertEvent(8,"a");
```

**several Events**

```
String oldText = "Hello world its me.";
String newText = "Hello world it's me, Tharmar !";
ChangeEvent several00 = new DeleteEvent(18,1);
ChangeEvent several01 = new InsertEvent(13,"'");
ChangeEvent several02 = new InsertEvent(18,", Tharmar !");
```

Because of the short time between these scans there shouldn't be much differences. Can someone please give me a feedback or advice how I could **identify** these changes and **log** them appropriately?

Comment: Wee! Diff algorithms! There are diff implementations out there, I think you should have a look at them...

Comment: do you have any experience with them and could suggest one which "could" fit? I've no direction where I could start to look

Comment: Google yields [this one](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/); no experience with it, however, you're on your own ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach may easily freeze browsers, especially with long texts. At a minimum, don't do a comparison if there were no browser events.

I think you may consider a different approach: log OnKeyUp events to track insertions, with backspace and delete keys being a special case - used to delete text. You may also need to track text selections for possible deletions, i.e. if a KeyUpEvent happened when a text was selected, this text was either deleted (backspace, delete buttons) or replaced with a new character.

And talk to whoever gave you these requirements. Try to convince them that it's enough to log what changes a user has made when a document is being saved. Otherwise you run a risk of seriously degrading the user experience.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll try this approach. It sounds easier and efficient at the same time :).